# Passing Aws url function directly in image uri makes the image change everytime when any state variable is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

In my react native app, I am using 'aws-sdk' which works fine but as soon as any state is changed, the image gets reloaded. I think react calls the function whenever the change is detected in my url. And as the aws sdk generates unique url the image reloaded each time a state is changed. I dont want to add an extra variable for image. Like to know how can I fix this i.e pass function in image uri & make the image immutable each time a state is changed. THANKS

My Image UI for e.g is-

```
 <Image        
   style={{width:100,height:150, resizeMode:'cover'}}
   source={{ uri:this.getAwsImageUrl(this.state.imurl) }}
 > 
 </Image>
```

And My getAwsImageUrl() is-

```
  getAwsImageUrl(imgUrl) {
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({accessKeyId:'test', 
    secretAccessKey:'test', region:'test'});
    var img='';
    var params = {Bucket: 'test', Key:imgUrl};

      img=s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);

      console.log('imgggggggg=',img);
      return img;

}
```

Comment: NOTE: I dont want to use any state var for this if this can be done directly as I mentioned

Comment: You are not updating the `img` variable, also `s3.getSignedUrl()` is used async.
You should try something like `return s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);`

Comment: The thing that I came to know is that if I pass a function in image uri & if that function returns some unique url each time along a state change, then react reloads the image also, like I use a random image & add current time in its params then my image will always reload . I can have a work around here by using another variable but I am using nested lists & data is very complex & i cant add a variable for every image I got. I've to find a way around here only. I've also raised the same issue on  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19178 for tracking